# PowerPivot Data Refresh

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powerpivot

We have a user who had configured powerpivot data refresh jobs with his account. So, when he changed his password, his domain user account is getting blocked because of many wrong log-in try. Can I use management shell to display all power pivot data refresh jobs using his account credentials? Or what can I do with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How PowerPivot refresh configured?  Was it setup with Secure Store? I doubt it but if so you will need to change the SSS credential in CA.  Otherwise I would inspect the settings of the data connection PowerPivot is using.

Comment: PowerPivot was not configured with SecureStore. When uploading excel documents, user configured with his credentials. So now I need to find all PowerPivot documents to change credentials  and there are so many documents. I don't want to check one by one.

Comment: Ok, I see.  If all the files are in a couple of libraries you could download the list to Excel and filter the data to generate a list of files the user created but as far as automatically changing the password or the account used for data refreshes I do not know of a way to accomplish your goal programmatically.

Comment: There are so many documents in so many libraries uploaded by the user. Checking eachy library and each document for the user will have very much time. I was hoping to find a powershell cmdlet to iterate all documents which is using users credentials.